# Angular does not update the HTML of a component when it changes in another component

Tags: html, angular, typescript, dom

I am writing an online store on Spirng Boot + Angular. Faced with the following problem: the HTML is not updated when I update an array that is associated with *ngFor elements. This happens only when a method of another component is called from one component.
Template of the first component:

```
<button  class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" (click) = "chooseCategory(cat.name)" >{{cat.name}}</button>
```

The firstComponent:

```
   constructor(private productList: ProductListComponent, 
private categoryService: CategoryService, 
private paginationC: ProductPaginationComponent) {
      }
    chooseCategory(cat?: string): void {
        this.productList.showAllProductsByCategory(1,cat);     
        this.paginationC.initPagesNumbers(cat);         //calling the method of the second component
      }
```

The second component:

```
pagesNumbers = [];     //field 
    ngOnInit() : void {
        this.initPagesNumbers()  // it works
      }
    
initPagesNumbers(category?:string) {
        this.productService.getCountOfProducts(category).subscribe(data =>{
        pagesCount = 10      // It doesn't matter.
        this.pagesNumbers = []
        for (let i = 0; i < pagesCount; i++) {
            this.pagesNumbers[i] = i;
        }
```

Template of the second component:

```
<ul  class="pagination pagination-lg">
<li *ngFor="let page of pagesNumbers"  class="page-item">
  <a [attr.id]=page+1 class="page-link" (click)="showNextPage($event)" tabindex="-1">{{page+1}}</a>
</li>
```

Only ngOnInit works properly. Because it is called inside the same component. The function call is triggered from another component, but the HTML page remains unchanged.

What have I tried:

1. ChangeDetectorRef detectChanges();
2. ApplicationRef tick();
3. ngOnChange()

(I'm new to Angular and I don't really understand what all this means and how it differs, but I tried it in different places of the component.)

4. In the method of the first component, it takes the Observable object
   as the field of the second component. The situation is the same.
5. In the first component, I created a ReplaySubject that is subscribed
   to Observable in the same component. In the second component in
   ngOnInit() subscribed to that Subject. However, the information did
   not reach the second component at all.

Why can't I do it? Thanks.

**Added**

ProductListComponent

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
    <app-category-list></app-category-list>
  </div>
  <div class="col-9">
    <div class = "container">
      <div class = "row">
        <div class = "col-4" *ngFor="let prod of products; let i = index" >
          <app-product-view [prod]="prod" [count] = "i"></app-product-view>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <app-product-pagination></app-product-pagination>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to call the "app-product-pagination" method from the "app-category-list". They are sibling components and do not contain any other components.

Comment: In order to call methods on a child component, you need to create a ViewChild reference to them first. If you have an array of components of the same type, you need to use ViewChildren.

Comment: As I understand it, the child component is the one that is in the template of another component. However , I only have DI in .ts file. The picture is like this: I have a root component, which has these two components in the template, between which I need interaction. In my case, I caught TypeError: this.child is undefined

Comment: Right, but you don't access child components through DI

Comment: I got the error above by trying @ViewChild in a component from which I then called the method of another component. I don't quite understand you. Do you mean that you need to include the root component in both child components using DI? (tried)

Comment: No, you don't need to include *anything* related to accessing child components via DI. Just to clarify, are you trying to communicate between sibling components?

Comment: Here's a StackBlitz on how to access and call a child component method: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vrcqkh?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Yes, they are both heirs of the third (root) component (ProductList). If you look at my question, then from the chooseCategory() method I call two methods: the parent component (showallproducts...()) and sibling (initpages...()) component. Both take data from the database and render 1) the received products 2) page buttons. The first one works and draws, the second one only works, but does not draw

Comment: I can't tell what's going from your templates. Can you please add your complete template implementation so we can see the hierarchy of the components?

Comment: i added. A minute ago I decided to call the second method via the first method (the parent method) on paginationComponent and made @ViewChild instead of DI in the parent component. And yes, it almost worked now, but the page buttons are redrawn if you just click on them. And I need it right away.

Comment: Siblings cannot communicate via ViewChild references. You need to use a Subject via a service that is injected into both components. When your second component receives the subject value from the service, you can call your method.

Comment: More on component interaction: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: I have already tried to do Replay Subject. However, I tried it again in ProductService I created a subject, and in pagination Component I subscribed to it in ngOnInit. Multicasting works as it should. Only everything also does not render. I think I've already tried everything.

Comment: What is the change detection strategy of your components?